# Card with 3D effect for WordPress post archive items

Tags: html, css, wordpress, archive, card

With Bricks Builder in WordPress I want to make a card for the loop items on an archive page.

The card itself is not the problem, but I don't get the schadow/3D effect exactly like the design.

I thought to use a `div` for the card itself, in it an image with a `div` above it for the icon with `position: absolute;`. Below a `div` with the title in it and below a `div` with 2 divs in it for the category and date.

The blue background is not relevant to the card.

I've already tried it with `:before` and `:after` with `skew`, but then the oblique angle at the bottom is not right. It has to be exactly the other way around. I also wonder if the way I've done it now is neat and doesn't cause any problems on mobile.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

[image: What it should be]

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Without any code, we can't help. Unrelated, was just in Enschede - beautiful city and country!

Comment: Maybe you should turn to some freelance platform?